# How to notify failure of ddl,dml scripts through jenkins?

Tags: sql, jenkins, notifications, ddl, dml

We have configured a job to execute the .ddl & .dml files through jenkins.
We want to get notified when some code inside a dml or ddl file throws an error. 
Can we do this through jenkins plugins. If Yes which plugin & how?

Comment: How are you executing this job? via Shell execution step?
Jenkins tracks exit codes - so if your step will be configured to send non-zero exit code on scenarios you consider as failure this may do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches.  Depending how you run the scripts, Jenkins will fail the build if there are non zero exit code.

Another appproach we use is Log Praser plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin . You can look for specific error string and fail with messsage.  Then integrate this with [Failure Cause Management](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer)    plugin.  It can given quick diagnostic message to the end user.